# Validacion de campos PHP

Tags: php, sql

Tengo funcionando ya mi index en el cuál realizo el logueo con usuario y contraseña, la cuestión es que al momento de dar espacio en blanco en ambos campos permite ingresar al menú, alguna sentencia en script o php para validar y evitar que esto ocurra?

código del formulario:

```
<center><form name='login' class="register" method='post' action='login.php'>

              <tr>
                 <td><label>Usuario:</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><input type='text'  class="register-input" required name='Usuario' maxlenght='10'></label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><label>Clave/RP:</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><input type='password' class="register-input" required name='RPE'></label><br><br></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><center><input type='submit' class="register-button" id='boton' value='Iniciar sesión'></label></center></td>
              </tr> 

  </form></center>
```

código de login.php

```
   <div class="menu" id=registro>
   <?php session_start();

    $Usuario=$_POST['Usuario'];
    $RPE=$_POST['RPE'];
    $query = "SELECT idAdmin, Usuario FROM administradores WHERE 
     Usuario='$Usuario' AND    RPE='$RPE'";

    include('libreria.php');
    $result=conectar_bd($query);
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

           $_SESSION['idAdmin']=$row[0];
           $_SESSION['Usuario']=$row[1];
             header ("Location: menu.php");

         }
         else
         {
           echo "<center>ERROR: No existe el usuario o la clave es incorrecta. <br><br></center>";
           echo "<center><a href='index.php'>INTENTAR DE NUEVO</a><br> 
     </center>";
           }       
     ?>     
     <center><img src="images/error.png" width="350" height="250" alt="Logo 
CFE"/</center>
  </div>
```

Comment: De que menu hablas?

Comment: Acceder a mi menú pues, al que yo estoy redirigiendo cuando la identificación login sea exitosa

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es que se eliminen todos los espacios en blanco de los dos inputs, o que se elimine la posibilidad de que un usuario meta un espacio en blanco en cada input?

Comment: La segunda opción

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción sencilla para tu solución sería añadir un patrón para que filtre el primer espacio en tus inputs. De la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="text" class="" name="" maxlenght="10" pattern="[^ ].*" required>
```

Y lo mismo para el input de la contraseña. Lo que hacemos aquí es decirle que el primer carácter puede ser cualquiera salvo un espacio en blanco.

Además, si también quieres evitar otros tipos de espacios como tabulaciones puedes usar lo siguiente: `pattern="\S.*"`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, al parecer me funciono a la perfección

Answer (score 4):

Puedes en las variables que contienen el valor de tus inputs, del método TRIM que ayuda a eliminar espacios en blanco al inicio y al fin

**Sin Trim()**

```
<?php

$cadenaUno = "    Alfa";
$cadenaDos = "Alfa";

if($cadenaUno === $cadenaDos){
    echo "son iguales";
}else{
    echo "No son iguales";
}
```

> Como notas ambas cadenas aunque tienen el mismo texto, no son iguales
>   por los espacios al inicio y retorna como mensaje
>
> > "No son iguales"

**Con la función Trim()**

```
<?php

$cadenaUno = trim("    Alfa");
$cadenaDos = "Alfa";

if($cadenaUno === $cadenaDos){
    echo "son iguales";
}else{
    echo "No son iguales";
}
```

> En el ejemplo anterior, aunque la primer cadena tiene espacios al
>   inicio, gracias a trim() los elimina y manda el mensaje de que ambas
>   son iguales

**CON TUS VARIABLES**

```
<?php
$Usuario=trim($_POST['Usuario']);
$RPE=trim($_POST['RPE']);
```

Comment: Y aplicado a mi codigo, como sería? o es decir cada una de esa sentencias va después de donde defino mis parámetros del input?

Comment: @JairMejíaLópez te muestro al final de la respuesta un ejemplo

Comment: sería del modo que te acabo de anexar en la respuesta @JairMejíaLópez

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias lo reviso y te comento como va